# "Много больше" или "на много больше"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

В последнее время слышу и вижу в письменных (печатных) и разговорных вариантах такие словосочетания:
***"много больше"*** и **"на много больше"**.

В **чем** разница и **как** правильно говорить?

Answer (score 3):

Из словаря:

НАМНОГО, нареч. (обычно при сравнит. ст.). В значительной степени, значительно. Стать н. сильнее. Н. улучшить качество продукции. Сегодня н. теплее, чем было вчера.

МНОГО  2. (в сочет. со сравнит. ст.). Значительно, гораздо. Знать м. больше кого-л. Бросить м. дальше. Росло м. меньше цветов.

Частотность в Нацкорпуе 570:470, то есть практически одинакова.

ПРИМЕРЫ

1) Это намного больше того, что было, скажем, тысячу лет тому назад. Надо признать, что и нарезных ружей у противника было намного больше. Но большинство его произведений не намного больше одной строчки.

2) Чужой след был много больше моего. Теперь я знаю много больше, чем ты даже можешь себе вообразить! Мать присылала много больше, чем он мог заработать в месяц. Здесь энергия поля много больше, чем энергия плазмы.

Скорее всего, разница в смысловых оттенках.  Намного больше - это обозначение разницы (насколько больше),  о чем и свидетельствует приставка НА. 
Много больше - это значительно больше.

ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ(раздельное написание предлога НА для числительного)

Давыдов усмехнулся: ― И на много больше? ― Хоть на тридцать гектаров, а больше. [М. А. Шолохов. Поднятая целина. Книга 2 (1959)]